# QCubed/QCodo ORM Left Join

Tags: qcodo, qcubed

I am using QCubed php framework. I need any information regarding manuals or doc about qcubed (or qcodo) orm, or if someone has experience with QCubed, please can help me build or make a left/right join using orm ?

Answer (score 2):

The [QCubed site](http://examples.qcu.be/assets/_core/php/examples/qcubed_query/conditional_expand.php) has an example of doing joins using the ORM.

Comment: Please don't just post links to tutorials or examples. These can become useless through linkrot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have a look at the [examples site](http://examples.qcu.be). Not only it contains the information about Db joins but also shows the capabilities of QCubed in various other fields such as Ajax, Form handling, Jquery control creation and so on.

Regards